# Ask for location permission popup in iOS mobile browser

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello I am using below java script for location permission which is working fine when we open that in the desktop browser and on an android device but pop up is not working on an iOS device.

```
(function () {
            function updatePermission(name, state) {
                console.log('update permission for ' + name + ' with ' + state);
            }

            function init() {
                var getPosBtn = document.querySelector('#getPositionBtn');
                // Check for Geolocation API permissions
                navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(p) {
                    updatePermission('geolocation', p.state);
                    p.onchange = function() {
                        updatePermission('geolocation', this.state);
                    };
                });

                getPosBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    getLocation();
                });

                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    getpermission();
                });

                function getpermission(){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function(position) {
                            var geocoder;
                            var city;
                            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function (results, status) {
                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    if (results[0]) {
                                        var arrAddress = results;
                                        console.log(results);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("address not found");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                                }
                            });
                        },function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        },{enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 10000} 
                    );
                }

                function getLocation(){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function(position) {
                            var geocoder;
                            var city;
                            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function (results, status) {
                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    if (results[0]) {
                                        var arrAddress = results;
                                        console.log(results);
                                        $('.location_input').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("address not found");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                                }
                            });
                        },function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        },{enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 10000} 
                    );
                }

            }
            init();
        })();
```

There is two case where I ask for permission from user when they click on location icon and on page load.Page load permission is not working in any device but button event click permission is working for android device.

Comment: any solution found ? please help me, I also faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all **[I am developing an Apache Cordova App with Angularjs]** , I finally came up with a solution that the user havent allowed for location permission in Safari. Then I just alert a dialog to user through which how he or she can allow for location services in Safari. Just as follows **[ and Error.Code==1 means user denied for location permission]**
After permission granted the error goes away :)

```
 $scope.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
                        if ($scope.t1 == 0) {
                            $scope.t1 = position.timestamp;
                        } else {
                            if (Math.abs($scope.t1 - position.timestamp) > 5000) {
                                $scope.t1 = position.timestamp;
                                SellerRef.update({ Location: { Lat: position.coords.latitude, Long: position.coords.longitude } })
                            }
                        }
    
                    },
                        function (error) {
                            if (error.code == 1) {
                                  $scope.showAlert("An error occured \n" + " Please goto Settings->Privacy->LocationServices and give permission for " + bowser.name + " which is your browser ");
                            }
    
                        }
                    );
```